# Измерение пропускной способности маршрутизатора

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, tcp, udp, маршрутизатор

Есть маршрутизатор уровня ядра с заявленной пропускной способностью 3 миллиона `pps`. Есть задача эмпирически это проверить. Спец-железа нету, опыта тоже. Выбор пал на программное решение `iperf3`.
2 компа с гигабитными картами соединил через маршрутизатор в соответствующие гигабитные порты. На компах запустил следующие команды:

```
#клиент
#udp трафик, пакеты 64байта, ограничение скорости 1Гбит/сек.
iperf3 -c <ip-address> -l 64 -p 1234 -n 1G -M 64 -P 16 -u -b 1G
#сервер
iperf3 -s -p 1234 -i 60
```

Получаю скорость `313 Мбит/сек`, `220 тыс. pps` (пакеты получаю [этим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243073/iperf3-results-in-packets-per-second) способом).

Собственно пропускная способность определяется суммой пропускных способностей всех интерфейсов или же заявленную характеристику можно получить измерив один интерфейс?
Если один интерфейс, то почему получены такие цифры? 
Возможно другие параметры необходимо указывать у `iperf`?

Answer (score 0):

Простое перемножение размера пакета на заявленную пакетную производительность устройства показывает, что подобную нагрузку невозможно обеспечить, пропуская такой трафик между парой гигабитных портов, т.к. результат превышает полтора гигабита в секунду даже без учёта заголовков ethernet.

Я бы рекомендовал при проведении тестирования:

1. Использовать нагрузку по количеству портов маршрутизатора, постепенно повышая bandwidth (одновременно на всех устройствах) до тех пор, пока он очевидно не упрётся в потолок пропускной способности.
2. Не задирать bandwidth выше 80% от номинала (то есть не ставить его выше 800M).
3. Использовать `-t` вместо `-n` (например, `-t 300`, раз уж у вас на сервере задано `-i 60`)
4. Начинать тестирование без `-l` и `-P`.